Grub bootloader errors
After several attempts, I finally had a headway with setting up what I like to call a plug 'n' play Ubuntu OS.
VM setup seems to have some limitations (especially sharing resources with host OS at the same time) and storage space issues ruled out dual boot on same SSD. So I picked up an old HDD drive and install Ubuntu 22.04.
Good news: installation was successful. Able to select Ubuntu or Windows with Grub bootloader.
Bad news: GNU Grub minimal bash like line editing is supported error whenever the computer starts up without the Ubuntu drive plugged in.
In order to resolve this, I:

need to reorder boot device from BIOS to have Windows come first. This means PC would always boot to Windows without being able to select a separate OS when Ubuntu drive is plugged in.
resolve issue with "grub minimal bash like..." error.

GNU GRUB 2.06
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub> _

I prefer the latter. I attempted to follow the guide here to fix this. But I got errors with grub-install.
grub-install: error: failed to get the canonical path of '/cow'
Any other way to resolve this issue with Grub when my Ubuntu drive is not plugged in?
I have the impression that I might need to install Grub on my Windows drive so it can easily access it during startup and then allow user to select Windows.

Boot with Ubuntu and install the Grub bootloader on the HDD. reboot with Windows and install the Windows bootloader on the SSD

You told the computer it has 2 OS and then you took one away. Based on just that it is doing what it is supposed to do.
